# How to use characters that are outside of ASCII code range in VBA OR Any Alternatives of using *Chr* in Ranges in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have ***Excel* Columns** being used that are beyond *Z (Column)* ie *AA,AB,AC...*.When i run below code it gives me error as there as no ASCII codes for *AA,AB,AC...*.How to represent these *AA,AB,AC...* columns in ASCII.ALSO Are there any alternatives of using *Chr* in *Range* so that i can avoid ASCII codes ?

```
counter = 0
For i = 1 To 14
Data.Range(Chr(80 + counter) & lastcolmain) = .Range("y" & 3 + i)
counter = counter + 6
Next
```

Comment: Use `Cells` instead of `Range` and you can avoid all of this.

Comment: `Split(Cells(1,counter).Address(False,True,xlA1,False),"$")(0)`

Comment: @Chronocidal - no need for that, use the column number

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `Cells` and the column number instead of `Range` and the column letter:

```vb
Data.Cells(lastcolmain, 16 + counter).Value = .Range("y" & 3 + i).Value
```